# JavaScript in the world today

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Do you know how many browsers don't have JavaScript ?

Why would they turn off JavaScript in 2011 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers that display limited content, such as those for the visually impaired, and some other text-only browsers do not support Javascript. Most browsers let the user disable Javascript, if they so desire.

Other than that, Javascript should be very widely supported by any browser (not necessarily with the same level of support) that has been made in the last ten years.

Javascript will not be "turned off" anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

Some offices (like federal ones) turn off javascript in their browsers because it can pose a security risk. Other people turn it off on purpose because they're paranoid and some old school users who use lynx don't have it at all

Comment: What risks ? For user or site ?

Comment: Most online vulnerabilities are exploited using javascript for the users

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

There are actually two questions:

1. No, but I'd guess it has to do with the audience. Gov't may be less than average, gamers more than average (unless they have Noscript)
2. Nihilism? Nietzscheism? Other? Administrative McCarthyism?